# Vue 2 filter is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

trying to filter an array of objects with an input. I have tried multiple ways with no luck so far. it is telling me that my function "clients.filter" is not a function. get the same message if i set the code as "list.filter", the input for the search is actually part of a separate component and i'm not sure if maybe that is my issue. see below

this is my component where the clients are being gathered from api, and listed into data table

```
<template>
 <table class="table table-bordered table-light table-striped table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-primary">
      <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Type</th>
          <th scope="col">Email</th>
          <th scope="col">Phone</th>
          <th scope="col">Profile</th>
      </tr>
    </thead> 
        <tbody class="client-info">
            <tr v-for="(client, index) in filterBy(clients, searchClient)"  :key="index">
                <td>{{ index }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.type }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.phone }}</td>
                <td><router-link v-bind:to="'/client/'+client.id"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></router-link></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<script>


export default {
    name: 'client-info',
    props: {
        clients: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => []
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
        searchClient: ''
        }
    },
    created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('retrieveClients')
    },
    computed: { 
     filterBy (clients, value) {
         return clients.filter( client => {
             console.log(this.clients)
             return client.name.indexOf(value) > -1;
      })
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

next is the parent component where the list is actually being shown. I believe my structure is off because im using vuex. But anyways im not sure why it is telling my "clients.filter" is not a function.

```
<template>
 <div>

<!-- this is the buttons and filter above the list -->
    <div class="d-flex mb-3">.
      <input class="form-control w-25" placeholder="Filter By Name" v-model="searchClient" type="search">
      <div class="mr-auto ml-2">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span>Type:</span>
          All
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Business</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Individual</a>
        </div>
      </div>         

      <div class="btn-group ml-auto">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Import <span><i class="fas fa-download"></i></span></button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Export <span><i class="fas fa-upload"></i></span></button>
        <router-link to="/add" class="btn btn-primary pt-2">Add Client</router-link>
      </div>

    </div>


    <!-- the clients data is imported from client info file -->
    <div>      
      <client-info :clients="allClients"></client-info>      
    </div>



 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import ClientInfo from '@/components/clientslistexperience/ClientInfo'


export default {
name: 'ClientsList',
  components: {
    ClientInfo
  },
  data() {
    return {
      searchClient: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['allClients']),
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss">



</style>
```

another option i tried was defining my computed method as such

```
filterClient () {
         return this.clients.filter( client => {
             return !this.searchClient || client.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchClient.toLowerCase()) > -1
      })
    }
```

and then changing my v-for too

```
<tr v-for="(client, index) in filterClient"  :key="index">
                <td>{{ index }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.type }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.phone }}</td>
                <td><router-link v-bind:to="'/client/'+client.id"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></router-link></td>
            </tr>
```

but still no luck, all though i was not getting an alarm with that definition but i also wasn't getting any results either. any help would be awesome!!

Comment: Are you fetching `clients` asynchronously?

Comment: Doesn't `default: () => []` mean that it is a function?

Comment: Remove >1 from line which contains `includes()`

Comment: connexo, yes using axios to fetch the clients. the default: () => [] was what i though would be the definition for the array which is why im confused i guess

Comment: I'd expect `default: []`.

Comment: The `computed: { 
     filterBy (clients, value) {}` is not correct, if `console.log(clients, value)`, both of them are `undefined`. move it to `methods`

Comment: and for `client.name.toLowerCase().includes('something')` will return true/false, so don't need to compare with `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

When using

```
props: {
    list: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => []
    }
},
```

with default value an empty array means that if you define a component without passing a list prop then vue will use that default value.

For example, if you have defined a component like this:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</template>

export default {
    name: 'MyList',
    props: {
        list: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => [1, 2, 3],
        },
    },
};
```

and then define a component instance like:

```
<my-list></my-list>
```

your component would render:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

However, if you defined your component instance like this:

```
<my-list :list="['a', 'b', 'c']"></my-list>
```

your component would render:

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

Given that, and without knowing what your retrieveClients action does, what I can only assume is that the 'allClients' value that you pass to 'clients' prop is not an Array therefore the filter function does not exist.

Make sure your action mutates the state to at least an empty array if allClients is a state property. Else if, allClients is a getter make sure that returns at least an empty Array.